# Formatting Additional Captions Flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Im trying to create some flexdashboards and I have all the outputs generated Im just stuck on some formatting issues. The code below mimicks my actual project, including packages I need for the project, some of which are not necessary for the REPEX.

````
---
title: "REPEX flexdashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
    orientation: rows
---


```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(igraph)
library(ITNr)
library(readxl)
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```


Introduction
=====================================  

Some text to place hold

First tab
===================================== 
<h3><center> The First Plot and table</center></h3>

Row
-------------------------------------



### Plot 1
```{r}
data <- data.frame(x = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   y = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE))

plot(data$x, data$y)
```


### Table 1
```{r}
data%>%
  slice_max(x, n = 10)%>%
  kable()%>%
          kable_styling(bootstrap = "bordered")

```

Row{data-height = 50}
-------------------------------------
<h3><center> The Second Plot and table</center></h3>
Row
-------------------------------------
### Plot 2
```{r}
data <- data.frame(x = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   y = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE))

plot(data$x, data$y)
```


### Table 2
```{r}
data%>%
  slice_max(x, n = 10)%>%
  kable()%>%
          kable_styling(bootstrap = "bordered")

```
````

Theres an introduction page and multiple tabs. On the first tab with the plots, the first title "The First Plot and table" looks great and I want to repeat that format multiple times in each tab. For the second plot and table caption, I try and put it in its own row and use HTML to center the text and then set the row height to reduce the space. Im not having much luck so if anyone has any solutions or viable alternative it would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: can you share a screenshot and maybe draw what you are wanting, or maybe another screenshot of an example you have seen that you are trying to produce

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my issue and its a simple fix.

For myself on my computer, when setting the flexdashboard row height, there can be no spaces the height command. See below

```
Row{data-height = 50} #This doesnt not work for me, there is no effect the row height

Row{data-height=50} # This works for me, note the removed white space
```

Simply removing the whitespace in that specification works for me. This may not be the case for others but this was worked on my machine.